# Prestashop can't access modules

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I wanted to access the modules in my prestashop but then it showed me this error: 
[image: Don't know the meaning of this error]

Can someone tell me how to fix this error so that I can again acess the modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your employee account isn't type of SuperAdmin so I'm guessing you also don't have access to shop's database. Someone must have deleted a row from table `module_access` which defines your permissions for module ID of 186.

But if you have access to database and you know what your account type is then look in the table `profile_lang` and check what is the `id_profile` of your account type.

Then run this query to insert permissions.

```
INSERT INTO dbprefix_module_access (id_profile, id_module, view, configure, uninstall)
VALUES (youridprofile, 186, 1, 1, 1);
```

Replace `dbprefix` with your tables prefix and `youridprofile` with `id_profile` from `profile_lang` table.